# Return from function after catching exception

Tags: python

I'm writing little Python console apps that will be run by double-clicking a PyInstaller bundle.  I use exception handlers throughout the code to print nice error messages, but I also have a generic exception handler at the bottom to keep the console window open if something unexpected happens.  What's the best way to exit gracefully after catching an exception inside a function?  This will make more sense with an example:

```
def download_file(url):
    try:
        urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        return True

    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        print(url, e)
        return False

def main():
    result = download_file('http://example.com/nonexistent') or return
    # the program continues here
    

try:
    main()

except Exception as e:
    print(traceback.format_exc())

input('Press Enter to exit.')
```

That's how I would like for it to work, but the `return False` part throws a SyntaxError.  It works if I use `sys.exit()` instead but I don't want to do that because it will close the console window.  Why can't I do this and is there a better way?

Comment: `download_file('http://example.com/nonexistent') or return` is not valid syntax. `return` is a statement, it cannot go in an expression like that. You would have to do something like `result = function()` then `if not result: return`

Comment: I don't get a syntax error for `return False`; as predicted by the previous comment, I get it for `or return`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it works to say `download_file() or sys.exit()` so why does `or return` not work?  I'm not sure what the difference is.

Comment: @ElliottB neither `download_file()` nor `sys.exit()` are statements, each of those are expressions, basically function calls, the evaluate to a value. They can form parts of a compound, boolean expression (here using `or`). `return` is not a function call. It is not an expression. An expression *evaluates to some value*. It cannot form part of a compound expression, it is a statement. `return` doesn't *evaluated to anything*, it is a command which *returns control to the caller*. i.e. terminates a function. Just like a `while` statement, you can't do `download_file() or while True: foo()`

Comment: A good rule of thumb: you can assign the result of an expression to a variable: `x = y + z`, so `y + z` is an expression, `x = download_file()`, so `download_file()`  is an expression. You cannot do `x = return False`

Comment: Ok thanks! that is clear now

Answer (score 2):

Just change this:

```
download_file('http://example.com/nonexistent') or return
```

into this:

```
if not download_file('http://example.com/nonexistent'):
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be working fine, for example:

```
def foo(x):
    try:
        return 2/x
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return False
    
foo(2)
Out[14]: 1.0
foo(0)
Out[15]: False
```

I think the issue you're having is that your outer except clause is triggering before the one inside the function.